# .FormulaR1C1 Iferror(Vlookup runtime 1004

Tags: excel, vba

my code works when I take the IFERROR out, but when it's in there I get runtime error 1004.

anyone have an idea as to why?

```
Sub datacleanup()

Dim masterBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim dataSht As Worksheet
Dim rowLength As Integer
Dim ctrlPnl As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set masterBook = Excel.Workbooks("Working - Vendor Document Status Report.xlsm")
Set dataSht = masterBook.Worksheets("Data")
Set ctrlPnl = masterBook.Worksheets("Controlpanel")
dataSht.Activate

rowLength = dataSht.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

With Range("B3:B" & rowLength)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Controlpanel!R2C1:R100C6,3,False),"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `value-if-error` part of `=IFERROR` double quotes("") within your formula string using ""

change

```
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Controlpanel!R2C1:R100C6,3,False),"")"
```

to

```
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Controlpanel!R2C1:R100C6,3,False),"""")"
```

Comment: Thanks Thinkingcap, I guess it shows that I am new to VBA...that did the the trick!